Bazel install python libraries
I am new to Bazel and I followed the documentation to install requirements using requirements.txt and Workspace file.
This is my workspace file
...
pip_parse(
    name = "pip_dependency_1",
    requirements_lock = "//server-part/:requirements_lock.txt",
)

load("@pip_dependency_1//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")

install_deps()

But could not understand how to make a connection with my Build files. Where I run py_binary()
Thank you for your help!

Welcome to SO :)
Further down on that docs page, there's a heading 'Using third party packages as dependencies'. That outlines the usage of the requirement macro, which gives you an easy way of getting the label created by the requirements generator.
You can also find the label for yourself by looking at the generated .bzl file and finding the target corresponding to the dependency you're trying to use.

Thank you for welcoming me :) I couldn't find the requirements.bzl file so tried to add a dependency using requirements("flask") probably the name should be different in some way.

This is the error I am getting: ERROR: no such package '@@pip_dependency_1_flask//': The repository '@@pip_dependency_1_flask' could not be resolved: Repository '@@pip_dependency_1_flask' is not defined. Also, since I couldn't find the requirements.bzl file I am suspicious that there is something wrong with creating it.

I found out the problem, I have two requirements.txt files for different microservices. When I removed one, the error is fixed. Do you know if is there a way to use different requirements.txt files?

Can you use the src attribute, like here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/084b877c98b580839ceab2b071b02fc6768f3de6/examples/bzlmod/BUILD.bazel#L19
